# Creating a generic next button for UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, tags, uitextfield

I am trying to create a next button that works with the textField's tag.
I have this inside a void type method:

```
for (UITextField *textField in self.view.subviews)
{
    if ([textField isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
        if([textField isFirstResponder])
        {
            int i = _textFieldTag;  //starts as 0

            [[textField viewWithTag:i] resignFirstResponder];
            NSString *a = [(UITextField *)[textField viewWithTag:i] text];
            NSLog(@"TEXT 01 - %@", a);

            i = i + 1;
            NSLog(@"TAG 02 - %i", i);

            [[textField viewWithTag:i] becomeFirstResponder];
            NSString *b = [(UITextField *)[textField viewWithTag:i] text];
            NSLog(@"TEXT 02 - %@", b);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that even though `i` increments by 1, `NSString *b` returns nil and does not make that textField the next responder like I am expecting.

They are there, the tag exists, but somehow the new value of i is not accepted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You logic is not correct, and as @Greg said, you need to use `[self.view viewWithTag:i]` to get the correct view. Also, give self.view a tag that's different from any of the text fields' tags (you got the error because self.view has the default tag of 0). I think you want your logic to look like this:

```
-(IBAction)nextField:(id)sender {
    int i;
    for (UITextField *textField in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([textField isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] && [textField isFirstResponder]) {
            [textField resignFirstResponder];
            NSString *a = textField.text;
            NSLog(@"TEXT 01 - %@", a);
            //i = textField.tag + 1; // use this line if you don't want to go back to the first text field
            i = (textField.tag == 4)? 0 : textField.tag + 1; //use this line if you want to cycle back to the first text field when you are on the last one. Replace the 4 with whatever is your highest tag. This also assumes that the tag of the first text field is 0.  
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"TAG 02 - %i", i);
    [[self.view viewWithTag:i] becomeFirstResponder];
    NSString *b = [(UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:i] text];
    NSLog(@"TEXT 02 - %@", b);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try replace all of your call from:

```
[textField viewWithTag:i]
```

to:

```
[self.view viewWithTag:i]
```

You should ask view for viewWithTag not UITextField.

Comment: Sorry that made the app crash

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c15ca0'